# Trying to sort a vector of Books alphabetically using operator overloading C++

Tags: c++, sorting

Hi have done a bit of research and have found no way to do this.
I have a vector of LibraryBooks

```
vector <LibraryBook> l;
```

I am trying to sort the books by alphabetical order and am unsure how to do this. 
The class LibraryBook is made up of:

```
string author;
string title;
string numPages;
```

I want to sort the books by title, then if they are the same i want to sort them by author. I also have some overloaded operators which i need to use:

```
    bool Book::operator< (const LibraryBook &b1) const
{
   return author < b1.getAuthor(); 
}

    bool Book::operator> (const LibraryBook &b1) const
{
   return author > b1.getAuthor(); 
}
```

cheers for any help you can provide!

Comment: Why do you overload the same operator twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this comparator method:

```
bool Book::operator< (const Book &rhs) const
{
   return std::tie(title, author) < std::tie(rhs.title, rhs.author);
}
```

and then simply do

```
std::vector <LibraryBook> l;
// ...
std::sort(l.begin(), l.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this method:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [ ](Book &a, Book &b) { 
        return  (a.title == b.title) ? a.auther < b.auther : a.title < b.title ;
        });
```

compiled with `-std=c++0x`.